# Excel VBA Change Cell Value From Empty Lines Only To Blank Value

Tags: excel, vba, replace, conditional-operator

I am new to VBA. I have searched my challenge online but still cannot figure it out.

Below please find my challenge:
I have a table with 3 columns. Column A, B and C. I have 3 conditions to locate the specific row values I am looking for.

1. when column A = "Completed"
2. when column B not blank
3. when column C has no text contents (it has empty lines not blank value, so cannot use ="")

with these three conditions, the very first row (we can say columnC/row1) in my table example is what I am looking for. But in my data, the cells like columnC/row1 have empty lines but only empty lines (no text contents). I would like to automatically delete all the empty lines for those cells and make them blank value. The number of empty line varies. It may have 2 empty lines or 3 empty lines. Any solution would be much appreciated.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Completed | Value |  |
| Completed | Value | value |
| Completed |  |  |

Below please find my code:

```
Sub RemoveEmptyLines()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Completed" And .Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" And .Cells(i, 3).Value = "?" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "" Then
                .Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = ""
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next iteration way:

```
 'your code
  For i = 1 To lastrow
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            If .cells(i, 1).value = "Completed" And .cells(i, 2).value <> "" And _
                   .cells(i, 3).value = String(Len(.cells(i, 3).value), vbLf) Then
                .cells(i, 3).value = "": .cells(i, 3).value = .cells(i, 3).value 'to update the cell format
            End If
        End With
    Next i
```

`String(Len(.cells(i, 3).value)` means only `vbLf` characters...

Answer (score 1):

If empty lines means just Chr(10), this code could work:

```vb
    Dim sTxt As String: sTxt = .Cells(i, 3).Value
    Dim sTxtRep As String: sTxtRep = Replace(sTxt, Chr(10), "")
    If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "Completed" And .Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" _
        And Len(sTxt) > 0 And Len(sTxtRep) = 0 Then
        .Cells(i, 3).Value = ""
    End If
```